# How to install LIBSVM for Python 2.65 on Mac OS X 10.6.4 Snow Leopard?

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, python, homebrew, libsvm

I would prefer to install libsvm without resorting to the use of a package manager other than homebrew. Any ideas?

Thank you,
Michaux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and extract the zip or tar.gz. Run 'make' in the python directory to generate the shared library. You may need to add the location of the shared library to your path. The python modules are in the python directory. More information is found in the readme, also in the python directory.

Alternatively, follow the directions in the readme that's in the python_old directory.

There's also the main readme in the root of the archive.

Comment: Thank you for the help! What exactly would the name of that "shared library" be? Is it "libsvm.so.1"? Much appreciated.

Comment: Nevermind my last question. Used the Interwebs and the googler to learn about "shared object libraries". Much obliged :)

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
make
cd python
make PYTHON_INCLUDEDIR=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7/ LDFLAGS="-shared -lpython"
```

The -lpython was missing in my libsvm makefile, so I'm adding it here.